# Saving multiple dataframes to multiple text filles

Tags: python, pandas

I want to save a list of dataframes each dataframe in a text file, I've tried this snippet but I got an error.

```
for entry in os.listdir(basepath):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(basepath, entry)):
        list2.append(entry)

for df in list1:
    df.to_csv("E:/test2/" + entry for entry in list2, index = False)
```

> df.to_csv("E:/test2/" + entry for entry in list2, index = False)
>                ^ SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument

What can I do?

Comment: You want to save the data frames in `list1` using the names in `list2`. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for df, entry in zip(list1, list2):
    df.to_csv("E:/test2/" + entry, index=False)
```